# Как добавить надпись placeholder в Wordpress,если не получается это сделать через php файл?

Tags: wordpress

Тренируюсь в освоении вордпресс (на одной из тем) и столкнулся с проблемой при оформлении виджета поиска. Не знаю,как вывести надпись placeholder "Search here..." через functions.php. Пробовал кое что прописать в functions.php,но не вышло.На картинках пример,как я хочу и что у меня получилось.
[ссылка на мой код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12ca676b1419324eb1a939bb76abe82757bb4354)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function my_search_form( $form ) {
        $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
        <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search for:' ) . '</label>
        <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php echo "Поиск"; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search' ) .'" />
        </div>
        </form>';
        return $form;
    }   

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form', 100 );
```

Это если Ваш код, а лучше создать файл в корне: searchform.php и прописать там

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo site_url()?>" >
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="searchinput" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php echo "Поиск"; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="headerfont" value="<?php _e('Search', 'Ваша тема'')?>" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

для русскоязычной элементарно добавить `placeholder="<?php echo "Поиск"; ?>"` в код input

и вызывать потом с помощью:

```
 <?php  echo esc_attr(get_search_form()); ?>
```

Comment: у меня выдает ошибку,я прописываю в 'Ваша тема' название темы sparrow, но ...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Search' (T_STRING) in C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php on line 56    Что именно надо прописывать там? Название папки?

Comment: Если вы пока не делаете мультиязычность то оставьте __( 'Search...' ) вместо  _e('Search..', 'Ваша тема')

Comment: а что надо писать в  'Ваша тема'? Название папки?

Comment: и если делать через <?php  echo esc_attr(get_search_form()); ?> то где лучше вызывать ее? В sidebar.php?

Comment: нет, чаще всего название темы, которое является id для мультиязычных тем, это если она у вас такая.

Comment: Вызываете там, где вам необходима по проекту. Своя форма дает вам больше гибкости в работе, но и требует больше работы с кодом.

Comment: id темы? А где прописано id темы?

Comment: я просто так и не понял,что мне прописывать в  'Ваша тема'

Comment: Пока не лезьте в такие дебри, освойте общие правила, это уже для создания мультиязычной темы без плагинов вопрос.. placeholder="<?php echo "Поиск"; ?>" вот вариант так же элементарный.

Comment: напишите placeholder="<?php echo "Поиск"; ?>", что бы пока не заморачиваться.

Comment: я изменил проще.

Comment: а можете проще написать,что надо сделать? А то я запутался,что где надо писать

Comment: скопируйте тот вариант, что я скинул в function документ, вместо вашего и все

Comment: помогло,спасибо

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста и удачи в освоении WP)